# Permissibility of shortening long Brachot for teaching to children

Tags: halacha, blessing, chinuch-education

Many children are old enough to learn short *brachot* (and somewhat understand them, if explained), but don't have the memory/patience for longer *brachot*.

Frustratingly, many of the *brachot* that could be introduced naturally in a child's routine are long (eg. *asher yatzar*, *ḳiddush*, *birkat hamazon*, *aḥat me'ein shalosh*). One suggestion could be using (non-Hebrew) alternative phrasing (not a *bracha*) that expresses the intent of the *bracha* (eg. "God makes all food, thank you for the food" for *birkat hamazon*). However, one could also teach a child a part of the "real" *bracha* that the child can reasonably learn; one simple option would be the *ḥatimot* of the long *brachot* (eg. בא״י הזן את הכל). Teaching part of the "real" *bracha* seems preferable, since the goal is eventually to teach the entire *bracha*, and if the child learns part of it now, learning the rest later will be easier (and make more sense to them).

I was wondering whether there is discussion as to the permissibility of teaching the *ḥatima* independently of the rest of the *bracha*. Short of learning the full *bracha* all at once, is this a permissible half-way step? Is there any discussion of converting the *ḥatima* to one with *shem* and *malchut* (ie. בא״י אמ״ה) for the purposes of saying an entire short *bracha*? Might the age of the child matter: older than 6 or 7 ("*ḥinuch* age") versus younger?

A potential source against my suggestion is the rule prohibiting turning a long *bracha* into a short one (ie. turning בא״י אמ״ה גוף הברכה בא״י חתימה into בא״י אמ״ה חתימה; see [mBrachot 1:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berakhot.1.4?lang=bi) with [tBrachot 1:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Berakhot.1.7?lang=bi)). From what I understand, *ḥinuch* should be as close to the "real thing" as possible (see [1](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/63862/4940), [2](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/46217/buying-pasul-arba-minim-or-non-arba-minim-for-your-small-child?noredirect=1&lq=1), [3](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20442/may-a-child-make-a-berachah-on-a-pasul-set-of-4-species?rq=1), [4](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13785/4940), etc.). Thus, I presume that adding *shem* and *malchut* to the *ḥatimah* is impermissible, even for *ḥinuch*. But perhaps just teaching the *ḥatima* as a half-way step is not fully making a short *bracha* out of a long one?

A possible argument for just using the *ḥatima* is the allowance of the formula "ברוך (...) מחדש חדשים" for the unlettered (see [Sanhedrin 42a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.42a.4?lang=bi)), instead of the full *birkat halevana*.

Comment: I was given psak that teaching children shortened brachot was perfectly acceptable as chinuch...my kids use the traditional Ladino *Ya Comimos* in place of the Birkhat Hamazon when eating without me (though this has the rather humorous side effect that my daughter considers Al Hamichya to be a long bracha achrona). Just one data point but worth noting.

Comment: @Joshk any more information on that ladino text?

Comment: @Dr. Shmuel the wikipedia article on it is fairly well done and includes the full text, though it claims it is used as an addition to the Birkhat Hamazon rather than a kitzur version. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ya_Comimos . If you have young Spanish-speaking children it's quite useful, they can learn it easily and there's only one archaic Spanish word they might have trouble understanding in the whole thing

Comment: The classic case of abbreviating long blessings is OC 187:1. Whether there's room for extra leniency for children is another question.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2274&st=&pgnum=156

Comment: The MB in 187 talks about using the shorter version for children, and he brings the Bach in 192 who has a short version of the whole berchas hamazon. But this is about changing the middle, not using only the end.

Answer (score 3):

+1 for a good question, which is part *halacha* (law), part *hashkafa* (perspective on children education). Regarding the latter, there is a famous story told about [R Yaakov Kamenetsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Kamenetsky) (sourced from [here](https://torah.org/interest/childraising/) but also retold in his Artscroll biography)

> One of the great child-raising stories of all time is the one
>   involving Rabbi Yaakov Kamenetsky. The great sage was once visiting a
>   Jewish school in New York, when he noticed something unusual about the
>   mezuzah. It was affixed much lower on the doorpost than is customary.
>   It turned out that **this was an innovation designed to make it easier
>   for the children** to reach the mezuzah to touch it, thus making the
>   mitzvah literally more accessible to them.
>
> **Rabbi Kamenetsky did not
>   approve.** "Put the mezuzah on the upper third of the doorpost, where it
>   belongs," he said, "and let them use a stool to reach it. Otherwise,
>   they will grow up thinking a mezuzah can be put anywhere you wish. One
>   does not raise children with falsehood." No matter how
>   well-intentioned the idea, he did not consider it a proper educational
>   approach. Our goal is to teach children to be truthful, and our
>   methods must be truthful, as well.

Comment: Also featured in [one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13604/2) of my [favorite](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1134/mi-yodeya-launch-party) Mi Yodeya posts.

Comment: I'm not sure that story is 100% comparable.  There, the mezuza would be pasul if you put it in the wrong place.  Here, you might be yotzei bedieved with a shortened version (depending which bracha it is and what essential pieces you include in it).

Comment: This story appears in one of the questions I linked to in the OP. But as @Heshy said, why is this comparable? The mezuzah is an obligation on adults, whereas a child saying a bracha is no obligation whatsoever.

Comment: @magicker72 I don't know if it is comparable, but I find it relevant: R Yaakov's opinion was that one should not "draw down" the mitzva to the level of the child, but rather "elevate" the child to the mitzva. I don't mean to be critical to your proposal, as anything that draws children to mitzvot is wonderful, but thought the perspective of a master educator on a related question was worthwhile. In our house, I stuck posters with "long brachot" (al hamechiya, aher yatzar) on the fridge, outside the toilet, etc. and this helped